# Filter top 25 entries which changes the bar & line Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a Dashboard where I have a list of 100 entries of different frim names, I have created a rank measure and have add it to the filters to get the top 25 firms in terms of their sales and I have a bar & line chart at the bottom.

My problem is that my table data with the firm names & their other details is getting filtered but my Bar & line chart shows the data for the entire 100 entries its not getting filtered as per my top 25 firms.

I tried using the rank measure in its filters but still not working, but if we select an induvial firm or multiple firms it changes.

Can some please help me here, I want my charts to auto filter the moment I select top 25 button along with my table

Comment: How and where you have applied the filter? show a screenshot if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Rank measure created, you can use Filter Type "Top N" by Rank value.

To test the same:

1. Select the visual created.
2. on the Filters pane on the right, expand the firm filter.
3. Under filter type, select the option "Top N" and value as Rank.
4. Apply filter